# MS C# 2010 Express ChartValueType.Time not showing correct time on XAxis

Tags: c#, datetime, mschart

I would like to see a chart plotted vs time (here over 10 seconds, as example) I have a problem with the following code:

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "hh:mm:ss";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Math.Sin(i));
```

will show "12:00:00" six times on XAxis, instead 10 consecutive seconds. If I add:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 0.1;
```

I will get XAxis looking like that: 12:00:00, 02:24:00, 04:48:00, 07:12:00, 09:36:00, 12:00:00 and so on. What should I change? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "dirty" way to workaround the problem - add:

```
DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

and

```
chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.Time;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(zeroTime.AddSeconds(i),Math.Sin(i));
```

should now work.